# Split non-relational table into multiple relational tables

Tags: mysql, csv, relational-database

I have the following table of 60000 rows, in a MySQL 5 database, which is derived from a CSV file:

```
CREATE TABLE `smts_import` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AscCode` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `AscName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `RgnCode` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `RgnName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `SCode` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `SName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `AM` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AF` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LG` decimal(10,4) NOT NULL,
  `LT` decimal(10,4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ars_codes` (`AscCode`,`RgnCode`,`SCode`),
  KEY `s_code` (`SCode`)
);
```

and which contains much repeated data. SCodes are unique, and the relationship between the RgnCode and SCode fields is many-to-one, as is that between the AscCode and RgnCode fields.
I want to split up (normalize) the data into three separate tables in a relational manner, such that no data are repeated:

```
CREATE TABLE `ascs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a_code` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `a_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `a_code` (`a_code`)
);

CREATE TABLE `rgns` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `r_code` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `r_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `a_id`+`r_code` (`a_id`, `r_code`),
  KEY `r_code` (`r_code`)
);

CREATE TABLE `sms` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `r_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `s_code` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `s_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `a_m` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `a_f` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lg` decimal(10,4) NOT NULL,
  `lt` decimal(10,4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `r_id+s_code` (`r_id`,`s_code`),
  KEY `s_code` (`s_code`)
);
```

where `rgns`.`a_id` is a foreign key on `ascs`.`id`, and `sms`.`r_id` is a foreign key on `rgns`.`id`.

I've created the three tables and successfully populated the first two, `ascs` and `rgns`, with unique data from the `smts_import` table. My problem comes when I try to populate the third table `sms` with just the `SCode`, `SName`, `AM`, `AF`, `LG` and `LT` fields from the `smts_import` table, PLUS the appropriate id from the `rgns` table. And here I just get lost, I've tried many variations on the following:

```
INSERT INTO sms (r_id, s_code, s_name, a_m, a_f, lg, lt)
SELECT DISTINCT sr.id, SCode, SName, AM, AF, LG, LT
FROM sms_import AS si, rgns AS sr, ascs AS sa
WHERE (sr.r_code = si.RgnCode)
AND (sr.a_id = sa.id)
AND (sa.a_code = si.AscCode)
ORDER BY SCode
```

but I just end up with too many records. How do I write this insert statement to get the appropriate fields from all records from the `sms_import` table, plus the correct values in the `sms`.`r_id` field from the `rgns`.`id` field?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

"the relationship between the RgnCode and SCode fields is many-to-one"
So you also get many rgns.id per SCode.
If you select distinct rgns.id, SCode, etc. you will get each SCode more than once depending on how many RgnCode you have for it.
I would suggest adding a id column to the sms table and create a separate table sms2rgns which contains the one-to-many relations sms.id -> rgns.id

Comment: Ahh! Sorry, I should have written that as:

there are many RGnCodes in each AscCode;
there are many SCodes in each RgnCode.

Comment: So, for example, there are 80 AscCodes, 750 RgnCodes and 60000 SCodes. HTH